# mysql extract records from to specified quantity

Tags: mysql

Web client requests records by batches of 10 specifying the `from` parameter. How do I need to write SQL query to select records from 1 to 10, from 11 to 20 and so on?

Comment: What is table structure? What is your current query? What is sample of desired result? Where's sample data?

Comment: Try using the `LIMIT` clause with a specified offset...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` is what you are looking for

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `table`
ORDER BY
    `somecolumn`
LIMIT 0, 10
```

`LIMIT 0, 10` means starting from record 0 take 10 rows. `LIMIT 10, 10` would be the next page skipping 10 and taking 10 more rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use the offset of the `limit` clause and don't forget to order by a specific column to get always the same results. To get records 21 to 30:

```
select * from your_table
order by some_column
limit 20, 10
```

Comment: Well, may be. But it's not clear what is the question about. May be it's about "some named 'from' field between 1 and 10" or something like that